# ant p4changes type="submitted" errors out

Tags: ant, perforce

I have a directory structure managed by perforce checked out to my local system.
In my ant build targets of my java code.  I want surf down into some subdirectory "Subdirectory_Start_here"  I want to know what the highest change list information for all files under that directory.

```
-depot
 |
 |-Directory A
 |    |
 |    |-directory A.1
 |    |-directory A.2
 |    |     |-Subdirectory_Start_here
 |    |     |
 |    |-directory A.3
 |
 |-Directory B
```

My ant build.xml target

```
  <target name="snapshot" depends="fully_configured,set_revision_slot">
     ....... 
    <echo>************************************^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^${env.LOCAL_FS_PATH_TO_P4_MANAGED_DIRECTORY}</echo>
    <taskdef resource="com/perforce/p4java/ant/tasks/P4Tasks.properties" classpath="../../../lib/p4ant-2010.1.293250.jar:../../../lib/p4java-2010.1.269249.jar" />
       <p4jchanges maxmostrecent="1"  client="peterc_peterc-ml" property="platformVersion" longdesc="true" type="submitted" files="${env.LOCAL_FS_PATH_TO_P4_MANAGED_DIRECTORY}/Directory A/directory A.2/Subdirectory_Start_Here/*"/> 
    <echo>************************************PLATFORM VERSION^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ${platformVersion}</echo>
    <exec executable="${NF}" dir="${COMMANDLINE_DIR}" failonerror="true">
                <arg line="platformVersion:${platformVersion}"/>
    </exec>
</target>
```

According to http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4ant/p4tasks.html#p4jchanges  a type of "submitted" should be allowed.  Submitted works on the standalone p4 command.  But I am getting.

```
 'submitted' is not a permitted value for com.perforce.p4java.core.IChangelist$Type
```

If I take type out. The echo does contain a changelist number that is different than if I don't have a files property.  So it appears that I get the latest pending or submitted change info from "Subdirectory_Start_Here" and down.

Any thoughts?????
Thanks for any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit daft, but try 'SUBMITTED'.

```
 <p4jchanges maxmostrecent="1"   longdesc="true" type="SUBMITTED" />
```